# How to round a value using field codes in MS Word 2010?

Tags: ms-word, rounding, fieldcodes

I am using field codes to dynamic calculate some things. Through an ASK field I am getting an value.

```
{ASK myvalue "Enter a value"}
```

Now I use this for some calculations and want to display it as a rounded value to a specified number of decimal places.

```
{= ROUND(myvalue/575, 1) \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

If I do that it displays syntax error. There is no syntax error if I remove the ROUND function.

Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

The most likely problem: Word wants you to use the same delimiter character as you have set in Windows Control Panel (Regional Options or whatever). The default US/UK English setting is ",", but many locales use ";". In that case your formula would need to be

```
{= ROUND(myvalue/575; 1) \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Comment: I already figured it out (it really was the problem with the delimiter), but thanks anyway. :)